# How to have a top margin that's a certain percent of window height?

Tags: css, height, margin

I would like to ask for help with a specific issue. I've searched for similar questions, but haven't found any actual solutions. I'm rather new to CSS.

I'm trying to have a blue box called `buttoncontainer` that will have buttons in it later on. For now, I would like to format it so that the distance between the top edge of the browser window and the top edge of the blue box is always 42% of the window's total height. As the code below shows, I'm trying to achieve this by giving the box a top margin of 42%.

However, I can't do it. When I open the HTML file in Firefox or IE (which are what I have on my home desktop), the distance is clearly something different when the window is full screen. If it isn't and I start resizing it, the location of the box does NOT respond to vertical resizing at all. It does, however, respond to horizontal resizing, which I don't want it to do.

I imagine this MUST be a rookie mistake I'm making, but I just can't figure out how to get it right.

To reiterate, I want the distance between the top edges of the window and the blue box to always be 42% of the total window height.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
  <title>Untitled Document</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.9.0.js"></script>

  <style type="text/css">
    body {
      background-color: #C94735
    }
    
    iframe {
      background-color: #FFF;
      border: 0;
      position: fixed;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      width: 63%;
      height: 100%;
      margin-left: 25%;
      margin-right: 12%;
    }
    
    .buttoncontainer {
      background-color: #00F;
      border: 0;
      position: fixed;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      margin-top: 42%;
      /* margin-bottom: auto; */
      margin-left: 15px;
      width: 25%;
      height: 58%;
    }
  </style>

</head>

<body>
  <div id="container" class="buttoncontainer">

  </div>
  <iframe id="content"></iframe>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 5):

A porcentual value for margin-top will be allways computed against the **width of the containing element**. Thats why your relative  margin position is modified when the width of the viewport/container element is modified.
You could compute with javascript the value and assigned appropriately.

You could  try as well (only css level 3) using viewport relative units. ( 1vw = 1% of viewport width and 1vh = 1% of viewport height)

Solution working here in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Fico/aKkwx/) where i modified buttoncontainer class as so;

```
.buttoncontainer {
....
....
margin-top: 42vh;
}
```

Comment: Just a friendly reminder: viewport units are not widely supported. [Browser Support](http://caniuse.com/viewport-units)